# MongoDb $elemMatch is not working as expected

Tags: mongodb

I'm writing a simple query that's using objects with propery `Tags` and has to return a document if following is true:

1. It has exactly 3 items
2. One of them is `:image`
3. One of them starts with `:` but is not an image
4. One of them doesn't start with `:`

So I want records of type `{ Tags : [":image", ":ianything", "somethingelse"] }`

I write following:

```
db.myCollection.find({
  Tags: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $eq: ":image"
    },
    $elemMatch: {
      $ne: ":image",
      $regex: /^:\w+$/
    },
    $elemMatch: {
      $regex: /^\w+$/
    },
    $size: 3
  }
}).limit(50)
```

But it doesn't work as expected and return items like `{ Tags : [":image", "something", "somethingelse"] }`

Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) to combine conditions:

```
db.myCollection.find({ $and: [
  { Tags: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $eq: ":image"
  } } },
  { Tags: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $ne: ":image",
      $regex: /^:\w+$/
  } } },
  { Tags: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $regex: /^\w+$/
  } } },
  { Tags: { $size: 3 } }
] });
```